# WPF ListBox grow up on Event Handler?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am extremely new using C# and that's far away from my mechanical skills ... I have very basic knowledge in C# but I am really willing to push the knowledge effort. Thanks to keep it in minde.

I creating some sort of application/ERP to help with working with my suppliers. The final goal is to create a list of suppliers, their skills, consult RFQ, update RFQ, send emails, ... I have been doing it in Excel VBA in the past but now I am willing to build up something stronger (and also willing to learn something new ...).

First of all, I am willing to create a ListBox with different kind of processes. I would like this ListBox to only show one ListBoxItems (one row) and when the mouse is entering into the ListBox, grow the ListBox to it's full size.
(My goal would be to ! create a ListBox with a dropdown for multiselection :=))

The dirty way I was thinking doing it is:

- Create a TextBox with "Click to expand" text. When the mouse is entering the Textbox, hide it and change the listbox visibility to Visible (default visibility to Hidde);

Any thought about it ? Where should I start by ?

I will then selected multiple items in my ListBox.

Latter on, I would like to binding ListBox content to a data base (don't know how to create it on my computer).

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Cheers

Edit:

Below is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="ERP_Fournisseurs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ERP_Fournisseurs"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ERP Fournisseurs" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas>
        <TabControl Height="369" Width="734" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="9">
            <TabItem Header="Ajouter fournisseurs">
                <Canvas Margin="0,0,0,-1">
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Fournisseur" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Nom fournisseur" Canvas.Top="16" />
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="NomTXT" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer nom fournisseur" Canvas.Top="14" Width="225" MouseDoubleClick="NomFournisseur_MouseDoubleClick" TextChanged="NomTXT_TextChanged" />
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Telephone" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Telephone" Canvas.Top="55"/>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="TelTXT" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer téléphone fournisseur" Canvas.Top="55" Width="225" MouseDoubleClick="TelTXT_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Mail" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Mail" Canvas.Top="84"/>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="MailTXT" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer adresse e-mail" Canvas.Top="91" Width="225" MouseDoubleClick="MailTXT_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Adresse" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Adresse" Canvas.Top="124"/>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="AdresseTXT" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer adresse" Canvas.Top="127" Width="225" MouseDoubleClick="AdresseTXT_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Types" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Types" Canvas.Top="157"/>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="TypesTXT" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer types" Canvas.Top="162" Width="225" />
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Procédés" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Procédés" Canvas.Top="194"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Matériaux" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Matériaux" Canvas.Top="232"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Délais" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Délais" Canvas.Top="258"/>
                    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Name="Autres" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Autres" Canvas.Top="289"/>
                    <TextBox Height="23" x:Name="AutreTXT" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer types" Canvas.Top="289" Width="225" MouseDoubleClick="AutreTXT_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <Button Name="AjoutTXT" Content="Ajouter" Height="100" Width="75" Canvas.Left="563" Canvas.Top="107" Click="AjoutTXT_Click"/>
                    <ListBox  Name="ListBoxProc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" Height="186" Canvas.Left="409" Canvas.Top="54" Visibility="Hidden" MouseLeave="ListBoxProc_MouseLeave" MouseEnter="ListBoxProc_MouseEnter"  SelectionMode="Multiple">
                        <ListBoxItem>TEST 1</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>TEST 1</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>TEST 1</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>TEST 1</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Name="ProcTXT2" Canvas.Left="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Entrer types" Canvas.Top="196" Width="225" />
                </Canvas>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Suivi devis" >
                <Canvas>
                </Canvas>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Liste fournisseurs" >
                <Canvas>
                </Canvas>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Below is my XAML.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ERP_Fournisseurs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NomFournisseur_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            NomTXT.Text = "";
        }

        private void TelTXT_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TelTXT.Text = "";
        }

        private void MailTXT_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MailTXT.Text = "";
        }

        private void AdresseTXT_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AdresseTXT.Text = "";
        }

        private void AjoutTXT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AutreTXT_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AutreTXT.Text = "";
        }

        private void ProcTXT_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void NomTXT_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MaterTXT_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ProcTXT_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ListBoxProc_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxProc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        private void ListBoxProc_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBoxProc.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }


        //https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/listbox-in-wpf/ Binding ListBox to Data Base
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

- Asked google my solution, but it's answerless;
- Tried the following code (https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/696480/How-to-make-a-ListBox-grow-on-mouseover) but not working

Comment: You can start with triggers - they can react on mouse events. Please provide your current setup (a [mcve]) and also describe what you've already tried and where you're stuck on. Consider reading our [ask] topics too.

Comment: Tried to do my best to meet your expectations !

Comment: My goal would be to ! create a ListBox with a dropdown for multiselection :=)